# What does "set -f" in Korn Shell do?

Tags: shell, ksh, set

In the book "A guide to aix 3.2", it says that one may use the Korn Shell command `set -f` to "disable filename generation", but what does it mean?

What happens with `set -f`?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`set -f` is the portable (i.e. POSIX) way to disable filename expansion.

When enabled (by default or with `set +f`), filename expansion is an operation performed by the shell that replaces, when possible, command line arguments containing:

- occurrences of wildcards (`?` = any single character and `*` = any number of characters)
- ranges enclosed in square brackets (e.g. `[a-z12]` = any character from `a` to `z`, or `1` or `2`)
- non matching lists (e.g. `[^a-z]` = any character not in the range `a` to `z`)
- and character classes (e.g. `[[:xdigit:]]` = any character that can be used to represent an hexadecimal number)

by the file names that match them.

When disabled, these arguments are left unchanged.

```
$ pwd
/etc/samba
$ echo *
lmhosts smb.conf
$ echo *o??
smb.conf
$ set -f
$ echo *
*
$ echo *o??
*o??
```

Answer (score 2):

In both ksh and bash, the `set -f` command disables file name generation ("path name expansion"). It is equivalent to setting the `noglob` shell option (in both shells).

It prevents the shell from expanding file globbing patterns:

```
$ ls -l
total 0
-rw-r--r--  1 kk  kk  0 Dec 30 21:39 hello
-rw-r--r--  1 kk  kk  0 Dec 30 21:39 world

$ echo *l[a-k]
world

$ echo *
hello world

$ set -o noglob

$ echo *
*

$ echo *l[a-k]
*l[a-k]
```

To revert (clear) the setting, use either `set +f` or `set +o noglob`.